# "/bin/sh: C:Perl64binperl.exe: command not found" on Windows 10

Tags: windows, perl, path, openssl, mingw

I am trying to build OpenSSL on Windows 10 64 bit machine using Code::blocks and Mingw. I already installed ActivePerl and MSYS. I am able to execute

```bash
perl Configure mingw
```

without errors. The problems is on executing the MAKE command. Regardless I am using the windows command prompt or MSYS, I always obtain the following error

```bash
C:\DiscoD\openssl>make CC=i586-mingw32msvc-gcc RANLIB=i586-mingw32msvc-ranlib
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl" \
            "-oMakefile" crypto\include\internal\bn_conf.h.in > crypto\include\internal\bn_conf.h
/bin/sh: C:Perl64binperl.exe: command not found
make: *** [crypto\include\internal\bn_conf.h] Error 127
```

It seems the backslahes are removed from Perl.exe path, so the script cannot find C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe. How to solve? Thanks

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you using? After you run `Configure`, perform `grep -IR 'C:Perl64binperl.exe' *`. Then, for each hit (it should be the Makefiles), perform `sed -i 's|C:Perl64binperl.exe|C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe|g' <file>`. You may need to escape the slash with `//`.

Comment: OpenSSL version is the last numberd 1.1.2. Any file contain C:Perl64binperl.exe because the path is built dinamycall and I have any idea about what file is giving the error.

Comment: There is no version 1.1.2 of OpenSSL (yet). You are most likely either using 1.1.0, or 1.0.2.

Comment: Sorry, it is 1.0.2

Answer (score 2):

You should see this recommendation from the OpenSSL distribution:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.PERL#L30

> ### Notes on Perl on Windows
>
> There are a number of build targets that can be viewed as "Windows".
>   Indeed, there are VC-* configs targeting VisualStudio C, as well as
>   MinGW and Cygwin. The key recommendation is to use "matching" Perl,
>   one that matches build environment. For example, if you will build
>   on Cygwin be sure to use the Cygwin package manager to install Perl.
>   For MSYS builds use the MSYS provided Perl. For VC-* builds we
>   recommend ActiveState Perl, available from
>   http://www.activestate.com/ActivePerl.

As you are doing an MSYS/MinGW build you should ensure that MSYS perl is installed (and on your path in preference to the ActiveState version). Then try the build again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to change from mingw MSYS to perl MSYS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that opening the Makefile and searching for "PERL=" found the line "PERL=C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\perl.exe". Replacing the single-backslashes for double-backslashes (i.e., "PERL=C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\bin\\perl.exe") corrected the problem. Single forward-slashes also worked.